# git -- narrowing the history down to one subdirectory

Tags: git, version-control

I understand this is an unorthodox requirement and the background is too complicated to explain.

I have a big directory BIG_DIR that's being tracked by git. I have a SUB_DIR underneath the BIG_DIR, which is tracked as a part of the BIG_DIR.

Now I only want to keep the git tracking history related to SUB_DIR. I dont want to track BIG_DIR anymore, but I want to keep SUB_DIR as an independent repository, while keeping its history.

The whole BIG_DIR has no remote repo. It's all local. if that makes it easier.

Comment: "which is tracked too", you mean it is tracked as part of the repository that tracks BIG_DIR, or does it have its own repository?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen as a part of BIG_DIR. i edited the original posting. thanks.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a repo with a complete history containing only SUB_DIR, use `git filter-branch`.

```
git clone old-rep ./SUB_DIR_repo
cd SUB_DIR_repo
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter='SUB_DIR' --prune-empty -- --all
```

The `--prune-mepty` is optional; it will remove any commit that didn't change the content of `SUB_DIR` from the new branches.

At this point `SUB_DIR_repo` contains two sets of refs: branches/tags pointing to a new history of `SUB_DIR`, plus "backup refs" (`original/*`) pointing to the full history of BIG_DIR.  Honestly the easiest way to clean this up is to clone again from `SUB_DIR_repo`.  (For the re-clone technique to work, you must use a `file://` URL instead of a local path.

```
git clone file://localhost/c/repos/SUB_DIR_repo new_repo
```

for example.)

If you don't need all the history, of course you could just init a new repo with the current state of the SUB_DIR

Comment: hi thanks for reply. But when I did your command I got 

$ git filter-branch --parent-filter='SUB_DIR' --prune-empty -- --all
usage: git filter-branch [--env-filter <command>] [--tree-filter <command>]
 [--index-filter <command>] [--parent-filter <command>]
 [--msg-filter <command>] [--commit-filter <command>]
 [--tag-name-filter <command>] [--subdirectory-filter <directory>]
 [--original <namespace>] [-d <directory>] [-f | --force]
 [<rev-list options>...]

Comment: the manual seems to suggest parent-filter needs to be a <command>, not 'SUB_DIR'

Comment: I'm sorry, I was half asleep thismorning.  `--parent-filter` is the wrong argument.  Fixing.